# Add text value to adjacent target range via Vlookup macro

Tags: vba, excel

Good afternoon, I would like by means of the changed cell value macro function
in Sheet1.Range ("I15:I18") to introduce a text value based on Vlookup function, avoiding using the formula. This is the table that Vlookup function text is looking at:

```
    A      B
1   0     Low Risk
2   10    Medium Risk
3   15    High Risk
```

It follows the code that it doesn't work for me:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim num As Long
    Dim sRes As Variant

    Set KeyCells = Sheet1.Range("I15:I18")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        sRes = Application.VLookup(num, Sheet2.Range("A56:B58"), 2, True)

        Debug.Print sRes
        Sheet1.Target.Offset(0, 1).Text = sRes
    End If
End Sub
```

The actual score that falls in the range is triggered by another macro that it works perfectly. 
Here also follow the macro that works alright with a single cell:

```
Sub NumberVLookup()
    Dim num As Long
    num = 16

    Dim sRes As Variant
    sRes = Application.VLookup(num, Sheet2.Range("A56:B58"), 2, True)

    Debug.Print sRes
    Sheet2.Range("J15") = sRes
End Sub
```

I really appreciate your help in this regard.

Comment: You don't define the variable `Num` in the `Worksheet.Change` code

Comment: And you should specify which sheet `Range(Target.Address)` belongs to, just to avoid any issues.

Comment: Thanks. How can i define num for example please?

Comment: The sheet is sheet1. After that you think the code will run?

Comment: In the second procedure you set `Num=16`.  `Num` has no value in the first procedure.

Comment: The second procedure is a fixed procedure and I have put it on display to show that Vlookup macro works with fixed numbers. However I would like to make it work with a range of cells. Many thanks

Comment: Maybe you meant to set `num` to `Target.Value` before performing the lookup?  As posted, `num` is never assigned a value and so will be zero.  `Sheet1.Target.Offset(0, 1).Text = sRes` should be `Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = sRes`   Note also your code assumes Target to be a single cell: that's not always the case.

Comment: Do you think is it possible Tim to make the macro work without num as it maybe creates confusion. If I will call num X do you think will it make a difference? Numbers I would like to insert in my X  Vlookup vary from 0 to possibly 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim sRes As Variant

    on error goto haveError

    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Me.Range("I15:I18"), Target)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        If rng.cells.count = 1 then
            sRes = Application.VLookup(rng.Value, _
                   Sheet2.Range("A56:B58"), 2, True)
            'turn off events before updating the worksheet
            Application.enableEvents = False
            rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = IIf(IsError(sRes), "???", sRes)
            Select Case rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
                Case "Low Risk": rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = Date + 180
                Case "Medium Risk": rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = Date + 150
                Case "High Risk": rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = Date + 120
            End Select
            Application.enableEvents = True
        End If '<< edit added missing line here
    End If
    Exit Sub

haveError:
    Application.enableEvents = True '<< ensures events are reset
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim, have tried it and it works perfectly. Shall I ask you still a favour?  I would like to add a date with your procedure to target.offset (0,2) I would like to add a date based on Vlookup: if low risk date+ 180 if medium risk date+ 150 high risk date+ 120. Please let me know if it is possible. Many thanks

Comment: How is risk determined?

Comment: By the little table is posted up

Comment: A      B
1   0     Low Risk
2   10    Medium Risk
3   15    High Risk

Comment: 0-9 low risk;10-14 medium risk;>=15 high risk